# Very slow file transfer on external drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have this external drive that has some serious transfer speed issues. It starts off fast, but it quickly dwindles down from 180mb/sec to less than 10 mb/sec eventually going all the way down to 1 mb/sec.

The drive in question is a seagate 4tb usb drive: "Backup Plus". Internally, it is a slower 5400rpm drive.

I use this drive every once in a long while as backup, copying large files (~650megs each). This drive is also rarely used, with CrystalDiskInfo reporting 22 hours of power-on time and capacity-wise, it's never even reached half full (ruling out disk fragmentation). SMART stats appear to be all good. It's never been dropped/suffered any physical damage and I let it cool before putting it away, (treating it carefully as I never want to end up where I need to restore and it's a bad backup. >.> ).

Trying to check drive/file properties and attempting to eject is all very slow, but it does eventually (on the scale of minutes) respond.

Things I've tried/checking:

- enabling/disabling write caching - doesn't seem to make a difference
- disabling search indexing - no real difference
- checking for any usb devices that might be taking up bandwidth (only have mouse and keyboard)
- looking in resource/activity monitor + process explorer to see if there might be anything running in the background that might be interfering -didn't find anything
- reboot/replug -no change (starts off fast, and less than 1 file, it drops down to unusable)
- running disk check to see if any errors -no errors
- stopping any antivirus process - no change
- usb 3 cable - should be okay, using the same cable I've used with another external (seagate) drive
- power adapter - should be okay, using the same power adapter I've used with another external (seagate) drive

It's formatted as NTFS and I'm on a desktop running win7 pro. Using the default system copy at the moment.

Anyone have any last ditch suggestions on how to diagnose what's wrong with this external drive?

Comment: *It starts off fast, but it quickly dwindles down from 180mb/sec to less than 10 mb/sec eventually going all the way down to 1 mb/sec.* Initial speed is a speed (more precise - is close to it) of the writing to the cache (RAM), final one is a speed of real physical writing to your device.

Comment: yea, I can understand that there is a burst of speed at the start as it's cache fills up. It just seems the "final speed' of less than 10mb/sec is way too slow. I've had usb2 drives that would transfer faster than this. Just seems quite strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I think I've figured it out: I took the external drive apart intending to use it in a dock (thinking maybe the external drive's controller was at fault) and turns out it is an SMR drive. Looking up reported random write speed for such drives returns speeds roughly in line with what I was seeing.

Putting this here for anyone else (including future me) that encounters this.

Comment: I was going nuts with similar crazy slowness in Linux Mint and it turns out that, indeed, Seagate also decided to go SMR on their 4TB Expansion Portable Drive (PN: 1TEAPF-500, aka STEA4000400). After opening it up, turns out it's an ST4000LM024. SMR. Should be SMH 

This drive yielded a performance of FOUR MB/s under linux. My old Toshiba external does 60 MB/s. arghhh!!!!

Thank you for your post!!!!